# Сделать из табов ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, link, tabs

Есть выпадающее меню с табами, при разрешении меньше 820px мне необходимо изменить табы на ссылки на другие страницы, т.е сам блок с контентом табов пропадает, а табы становятся ссылками [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно реализовать? может кто-то сталкивался с таким? если не до конца понятен вопрос, отвечу подробнее в комментариях

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) для изменения внешнего вида. Можно показывать / скрывать блоки в зависимости от ширины экрана в пикселях. Можно изменять внешний вид элементов в выпадающем меню.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
    .legitRipple {
        color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Изменить ссылку можно с помощью  jQuery

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){
 if (screen.width < 820){
   $('.active a').href = 'http://www.yoursite.com/news'
 }
});
```

Comment: у меня был вариант запихивать ссылку в data атрибут и потом ее оттуда брать , хороший вариант? и все это повесить на resize и отслеживать ширину окна браузера

Comment: Да, если требуется заменять сразу несколько ссылок. Можно сделать два атрибута и при ресайзе заменять сылку из первого или второго, если планируется использование на мобильных устройствах.

Comment: ага, значит все таки не таки плохие мысли были у меня, спасибо, я думаю вопрос закрыт)